# Html5 How to allow only one song to play and to restart it

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hi i have been lokking for ages and can't find a answer. What im trying to do is to have multiple audio files on a website and to only allow to play one song at a time. But also if you play a song then play a different song then go back to the first song i want that song to start from the beginning not from where i left off. here is my code so far

```js
 document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
        var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
        for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
            if(audios[i] != e.target){
                this.currentTime = 0;
                audios[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }, true);
```

```html
    <div>
    <p class="song"><h3><strong>#1 Intro - The Oath</strong></h3><p>
        <audio class="playback" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005876.LOFI.mp3 controls='controls' preload="none">
            <I>Your browser does not support the audio element.</I>
        </audio>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="song"><h3><strong>#2 A State Of Trance Year Mix 2013</strong></h3></p>
            <audio class="playback" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005933.LOFI.mp3 controls='controls' preload="none">
                <I>Your browser does not support the audio element.</I>
            </audio>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your eventListener is off, not sure about the loop. Try this first:

```js
var myAudio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

for(var i=0; i<myAudio.length; i++) {
   myAudio[i].addEventListener('play', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
 });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="song">
    <h3><strong>#1 Intro - The Oath</strong></h3>
    <p>
      <audio class="playback" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005876.LOFI.mp3 controls='controls' preload="none">
<span>Your browser does not support the audio element.</span>
</audio>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="song">
    <h3><strong>#2 A State Of Trance Year Mix 2013</strong></h3>
  </p>
  <audio class="playback" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005933.LOFI.mp3 controls='controls' preload="none">
  <span>Your browser does not support the audio element.</span>
  </audio>
</div>
```

On a sidenote I don't think `<I>` is a propert html tag. Changed to `<span>`

Comment: thanks for the help, but when i try it it doesnt work, and it doesnt pause other audios

Answer (score 0):

You're listening on the document for the (propagated) play event, and so `this` is the document.

Change `this.currentTime = 0;` to `audios[i].currentTime=0`.